# Gating LED monitor backlight at 16 kHz

Tags: mosfet, led, digital-logic

I'm trying to make a circuit to flicker the LED backlight of an LCD computer screen using a TTL pulse at approximately 16 kHz - the aim is to avoid it interfering with a microscopy system by turning off the screen during image data collection. I have to admit I am learning how to do this as I go as I have little experience in circuit design.

The idea to turn the LED off briefly (i.e. for around 30 microseconds) is to use a MOSFET gated by the TTL to block the LED from its low side, and another to simultaneously reroute the current (approx 250 mA) through a similar load (two ceramic 450 Ohm power resistors in parallel) so that the LED driver doesn't shutdown. This is the approximate circuit, although the 5 V should be 50 V, and the ground is actually the low side of the LED which goes back to the LED driver.

[image: the circuit]

This works to turn the screen **on** rapidly (as measured using a photodiode attached to the screen) but turning it **off** has a delay of about 23 microseconds. See the oscilloscope traces below where the yellow trace is the TTL and the blue is the photodiode.

[image]

[image]

If I instead have the side of the circuit with the ceramic resistors always active the LED is somewhat dimmer when active, but blanks rapidly when the low side of the LED is blocked. When the LED is on it is also less stable as can be seen below (blue trace is again photodiode).

[image]

Is this slow switching off of the LED when current is redirected to the just activated resistor some kind of capacitive effect? And how might I avoid this?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a hidden ceramic capacitor across those LEDs, maybe ~1uF?

Comment: you can buy a "break-before-make analog switch" IC for a couple bucks.

Comment: Could you add in another fet to short out the LEDs? That should turn them off faster.

Comment: +1 on what @SpehroPefhany said. The LEDs themselves will turn off in nanoseconds. Can you draw a schematic or block diagram?

Comment: I'm using the builtin LED driver of the monitor and so it is a bit difficult to say if there is a capacitor hidden somewhere on the board the driver is on (I don't really know what I'm looking for), there doesn't seem to be anything other than the LEDs them selves on the LED module. What would be the way to measure if it is there electrically and what would be the method to discharge it to avoid this latency? @winny do you mean something more than the circuit diagram I put in the original post?

Comment: @Ben Voigt from what I can tell the LED driver shuts down if you break before making the connection to the resistor alternative load, but maybe what you are talking about switches fast enough that the driver doesn't notice.

Comment: @ Bryan you mean between the high side of the LED and ground?

Comment: @Adran right across the LED, anode to cathode. You might have to add some logic and a p channel device to make it work, but once they’re shorted out they won’t be emitting light.

Comment: Ah! Here’s the devil in the details. If you put a MOSFET in series with the LEDs, you will also disconnect the output capacitor from the driver. A schematic diagram is the method to find such details. A block diagram may suffice as well.

Comment: @Adran: oops I meant to write "make-before-break".  They are also available (not as many options, but still sufficient)